# Can WiFi strength cause slow speed?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance, wireless-router

I have a 50Mbps connection connected to a 300Mbps N WiFi router. In Fedora Linux the place I am, this computer has a USB WiFi antenna capable of 150Mbps, most of the time I get 50% signal strength, at this signal strength, it shows connection speed at 27-50MBps but from the ISP I'm only getting around 4-6Mbps.

I complained about the slow speed and the technician of the ISP brought his laptop and phone and showed the result of the SpeedTest on his phone and laptop, and it was around 45Mbps. But the computer with Fedora Linux which is little bit far away I'm only getting 4-6Mbps. The technician said it is because of WiFi and signal strength, I think he was lying, if the WiFi signal's connection speed is above 10MBps a 50Mbps connection shouldn't be a problem. I think they don't have enough bandwidth and when they came, through Mac filtering or IP filtering, they increased the bandwidth for his devices to allow it to get close to the advertised speed.

Is my suspicion reasonable? How can I confront the ISP with this irritating chicanery?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a weak signal, there is a higher probability of packet drops, which means that the underlying IP protocol will have to repeat packets in order to get the data across. This may be perceived as slow transmission.

Comment: In ping, there are no packet drops. I'm getting 100% ping with less than 3ms.

Comment: You might be able to try this site https://www.battleforthenet.com/internethealthtest/ which (according to them) tests for degradation specifically.

Comment: Avg. speed is 1.25Mbps.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is checking other people who have the same plan/ISP and see if they get comparable speeds.

If you bring your computer closer to the router/modem, does the connection speed get faster?

Comment: Any chance your Fedora machine is reporting MBps and the techs laptop is reporting Mbps?  The Bytes/bits issue is a factor of 8.  Also, what speed do you get when you hardwire in to the router.

Comment: It's not possible to hard wire to the router. Yes, I know the difference between Mb(megabits) and MB(megabytes). Fedora shows in megabytes, the technician reported in megabits.